# Mechanism for palladium-catalysed spirocyclisation of conjugated diene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organotransition-metal-chemistry

I'm trying to work out the catalytic cycle for the following process:

[image: Palladium-catalysed oxaspirocyclisation of conjugated diene]

I gather that the palladium will be reduced from Pd(II) to Pd(0) in the process and that the 1,4-benzoquinone is a redoxidant. However, I am not sure where the palladium would be initially inserted (possibly one of the double bonds?) and how the chlorine ends up on the final product.

Comment: Notice also the full equivalent of benzoquinone. This is used to oxidize the eliminated Pd(0) basck to Pd(II).

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to wonder about *which* alkene coordinates to the Pd(II) centre. In this case, they are conjugated and therefore can coordinate together as a diene, which is a 4-electron donor. Many pi complexes are known ranging from alkenes (2e donor), to allyl (3e), to diene (4e), to cyclopentadienyl (5e), ... so this is not something really surprising.

[image: Coordination of diene to Pd(II)]

Coordination of the diene to Pd(II) makes it more electrophilic. The pendant hydroxyl group simply does a 5-*exo*-*trig* cyclisation to form the C-O bond, generating a Pd(II)-allyl species. In terms of stereochemistry, the OH group has to attack *anti* to the metal. Deprotonation can happen with acetate, or the hydroquinone dianion that benzoquinone is later reduced to.

[image: Cyclisation of hydroxyl group]

This Pd(II) allyl species is an intermediate in the well-known [Tsuji–Trost allylation](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/tsuji-trost-reaction.shtm). In this case, the Pd-allyl species is being generated in a different way, but goes on to react in the same way. Chloride being a relatively soft nucleophile attacks the allyl moiety, again *anti* to the Pd, leading to a Pd(0)-alkene complex. The stereochemistry of the chlorine isn't indicated in your product but this is my guess at what's going on.

[image: Attack of chloride on Pd-allyl intermediate]

Dissociation of the alkene directly gives the desired organic product and reoxidation of Pd(0) to Pd(II) with benzoquinone regenerates the catalyst.

---

Looking this reaction up on Reaxys, it seems that it is taken from a 1991 article by Bäckvall and Andersson.<sup>1</sup> The mechanism posited in the paper is identical to what I have written above, and on top of that my guess at the stereochemistry was correct: the authors indicate that the product obtained was 99% *cis* (referring to the chloride and ether oxygen in the product).

Interestingly, with $\ce{Li2CO3}$ instead of $\ce{LiCl}$, the product obtained has a *trans* acetate. Carbonate isn't a great nucleophile so it doesn't act as one, but it can deprotonate acetic acid. The acetate ion thus produced then forms a bond to Pd(II) before it migrates to the allyl system.

[image: Brief mechanism for generation of trans acetate]

---

**Reference**

1. Bäckvall, J. E.; Andersson, P. G. Stereocontrolled oxaspirocyclization of conjugated dienes via palladium catalysis. *J. Org. Chem.* **1991,** *56* (7), 2274–2276. [DOI: 10.1021/jo00007a002](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00007a002).